# Task scheduling for windows process?

Tags: .net, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, quartz.net

What library do you use for task scheduling (in windows process).
I've seen [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/), but it is too monstrous.
Now looking into [ncron](http://code.google.com/p/ncron/), it looks tiny and cute, but there was no commits for last year and too little information in the internet about its using.
Any advice?

Comment: There's DemiCode Scheduler (http://www.demicode.com), a commercial alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Normally it is recommended to use windows task scheduler and not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: +1 to using Windows Task scheduler from the author of NCron. If something (eg "enterprise policies") are forcing you towards a stand-alone Windows service, Quartz.NET and NCron are both quite solid and certainly better options than rolling everything yourself.